# Problems using foxy version of rviz,the rviz display is not satisfactory

Tags: rviz, ros-foxy

The rviz display of ros2 is very stuck, and sometimes the path display is not continuous. I am using a laptop with NVIDIA 3060 graphics card.I'm sure my graphics card driver was installed successfully.[image]

But when I run the foxy version of the ros2 program, the rviz display is not satisfactory. When my frame reaches another position, the point cloud and path displayed by rviz stop at a certain previous position.
[image]

I want to know what is the reason. My bag is converted from ros1's rosbag.